# getElementByName not working for input/select elements within html table

Tags: javascript, html

appols if this is a repeat, but I couldn't find a similar issue anywhere. I've a number of select and input elements wihtin td elements as part of a table that I want to collect the values of for some validation within Javascript.
I was hoping to use getElementsByName javascript to collect said data, but it appears as if these elements that are within the table are 'not' collected (all node lists are empty lists).... however, getElementById does appear to work for these element values.

Is this a known scenario where getElementsByName cannot be used?

Extract of my code below (i've made it a shorted version, since actual table is a log larger, but made it easier to read:

```
`fc = document.getElementsByName('forwarding_class');
min_bw = document.getElementsByName('min_bw');
exact =  document.getElementsByName('exact');

//Do some validation on node list fc etc.....

<form action="#" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <table id="cos_policy" name="cos_policy" class="display table table-hover table-bordered table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr style="background-color: #7E0305; color: white;">
                                <th style="width: 10%; text-align:center;">Forwarding Class</th>
                                <th style="width: 10%; text-align:center;">Min BW(%)</th>           
                                <th style="width: 10%; text-align:center;">Exact</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="cos_policy_table_body">
<tr>
<td hidden=""><input name="class_table[]" id="class_table0" value="GWR"></td>
<td hidden=""><input name="id[]" value="" hidden="" id="id0"></td>
<td><select name="forwarding_class[]" id="forwarding_class0" class="form-control">
<option value="">Select One</option>
<option value="VF-Premium">VF-Premium</option>
<option value="VF-Enhanced1">VF-Enhanced1</option>
</select></td>
<td><input class="form-control" id="min_bw0" name="min_bw[]" style="width: 100%;" value=""></td>
<td><select name="exact[]" id="exact0" class="form-control" style="width: 100%;">
<option value="">Select One</option><option value="True">True</option>
<option value="False">False</option>
</select></td>
</tr><tbody>
    </form>`
```

Comment: None of your fields have the names you are looking for. `foo` is not the same thing as `foo[]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined the `name` attributes of the inpouts as `forwarding_class[]`, `min_bw[]` and `exact[]`. So you have to use the same values in your selectors aswell.

Your selectors should be

```
fc = document.getElementsByName('forwarding_class[]');
min_bw = document.getElementsByName('min_bw[]');
exact =  document.getElementsByName('exact[]');
```

```js
fc = document.getElementsByName('forwarding_class[]');
min_bw = document.getElementsByName('min_bw[]');
exact =  document.getElementsByName('exact[]');
console.log(fc);
console.log(min_bw);
console.log(exact);
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <table id="cos_policy" name="cos_policy" class="display table table-hover table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr style="background-color: #7E0305; color: white;">
            <th style="width: 10%; text-align:center;">Forwarding Class</th>
            <th style="width: 10%; text-align:center;">Min BW(%)</th>
            <th style="width: 10%; text-align:center;">Exact</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="cos_policy_table_body">
          <tr>
            <td hidden=""><input name="class_table[]" id="class_table0" value="GWR"></td>
            <td hidden=""><input name="id[]" value="" hidden="" id="id0"></td>
            <td><select name="forwarding_class[]" id="forwarding_class0" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Select One</option>
                <option value="VF-Premium">VF-Premium</option>
                <option value="VF-Enhanced1">VF-Enhanced1</option>
              </select></td>
            <td><input class="form-control" id="min_bw0" name="min_bw[]" style="width: 100%;" value=""></td>
            <td><select name="exact[]" id="exact0" class="form-control" style="width: 100%;">
                <option value="">Select One</option>
                <option value="True">True</option>
                <option value="False">False</option>
              </select></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: many thanks.. could not see that.... now makes sense.

Comment: @GeraintJones you are welcome. If this works, please approve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
`fc = document.getElementsByName('forwarding_class');
min_bw = document.getElementsByName('min_bw');
exact =  document.getElementsByName('exact');

//Do some validation on node list fc etc.....

<form action="#" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <table id="cos_policy" name="cos_policy" class="display table table-hover table-bordered table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr style="background-color: #7E0305; color: white;">
                                <th style="width: 10%; text-align:center;">Forwarding Class</th>
                                <th style="width: 10%; text-align:center;">Min BW(%)</th>           
                                <th style="width: 10%; text-align:center;">Exact</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="cos_policy_table_body">
<tr>
<td hidden=""><input name="class_table[]" id="class_table0" value="GWR"></td>
<td hidden=""><input name="id[]" value="" hidden="" id="id0"></td>
<td><select name="forwarding_class[]" id="forwarding_class0" class="form-control">
<option value="">Select One</option>
<option value="VF-Premium">VF-Premium</option>
<option value="VF-Enhanced1">VF-Enhanced1</option>
</select></td>
<td><input class="form-control" id="min_bw0" name="min_bw" style="width: 100%;" value=""></td>
<td><select name="exact" id="exact0" class="form-control" style="width: 100%;">
<option value="">Select One</option><option value="True">True</option>
<option value="False">False</option>
</select></td>
</tr><tbody>
    </form>`
```